# Best way to run service no matter the distro

Tags: linux, services, upstart

I am working on an application and want to make the script start on boot, and for the users to be able to run things like

```
service my-program restart
```

What i am seeing is there seems to be different ways between different distro if its upstart, systemV and what ever else is out there. Wanted to know how most people solve this problem is there some special command that will do this regardless of what linux it is. Or am i going to need init scripts for each.

Answer (score 0):

If you want maximum portability, you may want to ensure your script checks the distro first and then accordingly use the appropriate startup program method

```
 Pseudocode:

 getDistro ( cat /etc/*release.txt )
 startUp ( Distro )
```

Good luck